# Admob Interstitial ad, onBackPressed doesn't dismiss the ad

Tags: android, admob

Sometimes `onBackPressed` doesn't work when `AdActivity` is visible, so `InterstitialAd` can be dismissed only with the close icon.

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0'
```

[Issue in Admob SDK group](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/t8Ln93xvi3g)

Comment: So, what`s the problem?

Comment: @kAvEh why sometimes onBackPressed dismisses the ad and sometimes not?

Comment: some ads disable the back button programmatically for getting more attention. this feature is implemented in some ad services.

Comment: Same issue happening in my app, and in many other apps, i opened an issue in Admob SDK group:
https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/t8Ln93xvi3g